# ‘Dembele Cannot Have Said Much To The Referee’ - grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, headline-english

The title is from an article in [BeSoccer.com](https://www.besoccer.com/new/dembele-cannot-have-said-much-to-the-referee-722090):

> ## Dembele cannot have said much to the referee
>
> "I don't know what Dembele may have said to the referee but I don't think it's a long sentence because it's hard to hear him speak Spanish."

Is the sentence in the title correct? If yes, what would be the tense of the sentence?

What would be the difference between that sentence and this one:

“Dembele could not say much to the referee”?

Comment: The difference between this and "Dembele could not have said much to the referee" would be an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you think that it might not be grammatically correct.  How can you have an even in the past with a verb (*can*) apparently in the present.  Well, you can.  The sentence **is** grammatically correct.

The word *Can* is listed in the *Oxford English Grammar [OEG]* as one of many **auxiliaries** (words that help the meaning of some other verb.  Some such words can function as verbs in their own right.

For example, *have* can function as a verb in its own right, as in "I **have** a book" (present tense) or "I **had** a book" (past tense); or it can function as an auxiliary, as in "They **have** never seen the Great Wall of China".

The word *can* (apart from the misleadingly identically spelled container) only exists as an auxiliary, followed by some verb, and meaning *be able to*.  Sidney Greenbaum of OEG lists *can* among a long list of such auxiliaries, such a *ought, may, will, etc..*.  In the section on **verb phrases**, he subdivides the *modal auxiliaries* and includes *can* as follows.

> A. **Can/could**
>
> **1.**  **Ability**
>
> [2] I *can* just about carry it
>
> [3] I mean obviously I *can* write academic articles
>   [4] *Could* you be a bit more specific about that?
>
> **2.**  **Permission**
>
> [5] *Can* I borrow yours?
>   [6] You *can* take these - etc
>
> **Possibility**
>
> [8] *Can* this be sent? etc...

Later he continues to another category **(OEG 4.24 F:  Must, cannot, can't, have to, have got to, need.**  This refers to things, for example that **must/have to/have got to** be the case, or which *cannot* be the case, as in your quotation.  He gives an example very like yours:

> **1. Certainty**
>
> **[53]**For a start the patients *cannot* have been brain dead <,> otherwise they *couldn't* have adapted so well when awakened.

In other words,

> For a start it is impossible for the patients to have been brain dead, because they adapted too well when awakened **for that to be (medically) possible**.

So a reason is given for the assertion that the circumstance (that a patient was 'brain dead' but then recovered **cannot have been** the case.

In your quotation, the journalist does not give give any reason **why** it cannot have been the case.  But in the article you link to, it is clear that the situation involved the reason for the referee sending Dembelele of the field with a red card is supposed to be the use of defiant or abusive language.  It is also clear that the team manager thought that whatever it was that Dembelele said was very short. One spectator comments that she thought Dembelele said "muy malo" ("very bad").  If she is right, then the manager was right:  Dembelele **didn't** say much, either in length or offensiveness.  If not there are plenty of worse things Dembelele could have said in French or, for that matter, Spanish that would have been very offensive indeed.

In the context of what the commentator wrote, a correct, only slightly different alternative would have been:-

> Dembelele *couldn't* have said much to the referee.

Your alternative ("Dembelele couldn't say much to the referee.") is correct English, but means something slightly different.  That would mean that the player would have been unable to say much the referee, because (for example) his team captain got between them and pushed him back, shouting at him to shut up.

*Cannot* is present, and refers to the (present) **fact that** it cannot (**now**) be the case that Dembelele (**then**) said much.  If you use *couldn't have* then the sentence is entirely related to the past: a slight but real difference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's perfectly correct. *Cannot have* here means that the writer thinks it impossible that Dembele said very much to the Spanish referee (because he knows that Dembele speaks little Spanish). It is expressing an opinion he has now about an incident in the past.

'Dembele could not say much to the referee' is just a statement about that past incident.

Comment: What about:  "Dembele could not have said much to the referee"? as mentioned in another comment, to the question?

Comment: What would be the tense of "can't have said"?

Comment: _Can_ is a modal verb that has only present and past tense. _He cannot have said_ = It is not possible (present) that he said (past). _He could not have said_ = It would not have been possible (past) for him to say. _He could not say_ = It was not possible for him to say.